# C# open text file

Tags: c#

On doc.microsoft site,we have streamreader solution like this

```
using System;
using System.IO;

class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        try
        {   // Open the text file using a stream reader.
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("TestFile.txt"))
            {
            // Read the stream to a string, and write the string to the console.
                String line = sr.ReadToEnd();
                Console.WriteLine(line);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The file could not be read:");
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

But I have also come across different examples like this

```
FileStream fin = null;
try {
  fin = new FileStream("test", FileMode.Open);
}

catch(IOException exc) {
  Console.WriteLine(exc.Message);
}
```

Is there any advantage in defining nullable FileStream?

Comment: Aren't that apples and oranges you're comparing?

Comment: A StreamReader still has a Stream (a FileStream in this case) under the hood. It takes the Stream (binary data) and presents it as Unicode text. Just look at the methods on both classes and decide which one will be most useful for your intended usage.

Comment: @rene Do not know,that is why I am asking.

Comment: The two examples are completely different in what they do. Without context it is impossible to answer *Is there any advantage in defining nullable FileStream?* and it certainly seems off with the title of your question.

Comment: @rene I have realized the difference,I am new to C#.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first example, the StreamReader is *not* available outside of the `try` block (and will be `Dispose()`d of anyway).

In the second example, the FileStream *is* available outside of the `try` block, but may be null (when an exception happened). It is up to you to Dispose of it later.